# How to compare dates with np.nanmin()

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to compare dates with NaNs included.

I used np.nanmin because this function excludes NaNs. However, this does not seem to work with dates.

I could write an apply() function, but because of the size of the dataset I would rather like to use a numpy-function. Any suggestions?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[dt.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0),
dt.datetime(2017, 2, 1, 0, 0)],dt.datetime(2017, 3, 1, 0, 0), np.nan]]),
                   columns=['date1', 'date2'])

np.nanmin([df['date1'], df['date2']], axis=0)
```

I expect:

```
['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01']
```

I got:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Comment: Use `df[['date1','date2']].min(axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you, this works! Still, I don't understand why np.nanmin() creates this error. If I do the same procedure with numbers (and NaNs) or dates (without NaNs), np.nanmin() works fine.